# Variable set but not used? (C++)

Tags: c++, variables, cygwin

I am brand new to C++ and programming in general. When I compile my code in the Cygwin compiler, I am given the error:

```
insurance.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
insurance.cpp:14:5: warning: variable ‘premium’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 int premium = 0;
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string maritalStatus;
int age;

cout << "Enter marital status (s=single, m=married): ";
cin >> maritalStatus;

cout << "Enter your age in years: ";
cin >> age;

int premium = 0;

if (maritalStatus == "m") {
 if (age < 21) {
     premium = 1200;
 } else if (age <= 29) {
     premium = 1000;
 } else {
     premium = 800;
 }
} else {
 if (maritalStatus == "s") {
    if (age < 21) {
       premium = 1500;
 } else if (age <=29) {
    premium = 1200;
 } else {
    premium = 1000;
 }
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You only set this variable but never doing anything with it. some statement like `std::cout >> premium >> std::endl;` would make the warning go away.

Comment: anyway, this is a warning, not error

Answer (score 2):

You have allocated `premium` and give it an initial value of zero. Then, you have edit it based on some conditions. However, you have never get any benefit of it.

For example, You did not print it. You did not pass it to another function. You did not use it as part of another expression. Simply, `premium` is useless variables that has nothing to do in your code.

**How to fix this?**

it depends on what you want to do with `premium`. If you really do not want to do anything with it, just delete it and delete anything related to it. If you want for example to print it, you may add this line at the end (before `return 0`):

```
std::cout << premium;
```

The answer depends on your usecase.

Comment: How could I fix this? Thanks for the reply.